# Fail2ban is started but am not seeing any activity on journalctl

Tags: fail2ban

I installed fail2ban, created .local versions of the supplied config files and started the service. The service is started as below. However I see no entries whatsoever in journalctl. How do I know it is doing any blocking?

```
● fail2ban.service - LSB: Start/stop fail2ban
```

Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/fail2ban; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-10-26 13:06:56 IST; 2h 53min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 25328 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/fail2ban start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 26 13:06:56 brahmaforces systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop fail2ban...
Oct 26 13:06:56 brahmaforces systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/stop fail2ban.

Comment: You can use fail2ban-client

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't see any activity in journalctl... well for most Distros you'll see no activity.

More likely you'll find fail2ban logging routes to a log file like...

```
/var/log/fail2ban.log
```

Try this, to determine your log target...

```
grep logtarget /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf
```